# Handling same function names in multiple AWS Lambdas

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a BitBucket repo which holds code for multiple lambda functions in separate folders. In two of the folders (belonging to separate lambdas), I'm using a same Python function name which has different number of arguments on different lambdas.

This is being identified by Sonar as a bug.

How do I handle my lambdas in such a scenario? Changing the name of the function in either of the lambdas is difficult to implement as I have references to this function from multiple places. Can I edit my Sonar ruleset to accomodate these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do a separate SQ project for each lambda, so that SQ does not mix up code belonging to different projects. My own best practice is that SQ should reflect the code that you build, not the code that you store (i.e. create SQ projects by projects outcome, not by Git repositories).

Comment: I agree that separating lambdas make sense but I'm charged for each of my SQ project. So, I have my SQ project mapped to a couple of repos each holding code for a few lambdas. Separating my lambda will increase my SQ cost by 5 times!